# Counting how many regular polygons combinations can form 360 degrees around a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles, polygons

A set of regular polygons of side length 1 is chosen such that the polygons can be made to fill the 360-degree angle around a point, as a hexagon, two squares, and a triangle can. In how many ways can the polygons be chosen? (the order of placement is irrelevant)

I have used a computer program and it has calculated that there are 17 solutions but now im curious and want to prove this but I don't know where to start.As a tip, the problem was in a section involving orthocenter, tangents, homothecy, and similar/congruent triangles. 
Any solution/proof or even a hint will be much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the facts that a regular $n-$gon has angles of $180-\frac {360}n$ degrees and you need a total of $360$ degrees at the vertex.  For six polygons, you need them all to be triangles.  For five polygons you can have four triangles and a hexagon or three triangles and two squares.  For four polygons, let the numbers of sides be $n1 \le n2 \le n3 \le n4$.  Then we have $360=720-\frac {360}{n1}-\frac {360}{n2}-\frac {360}{n3}-\frac {360}{n4}$ or $1=\frac 1{n1}+\frac 1{n2}+\frac 1{n3}+\frac1{n4}$.  Clearly one solution is $n1=n2=n3=n4=4$ with four squares.  You can't have three triangles because that leaves a straight angle.  If you have two triangles you need $\frac 1{n3}+\frac 1{n4}=\frac 13$, which can be two hexagons or a square and a dodecagon.  With one triangle you can have two squares and a hexagon.  Finally you can do the same for three.  The equation is $360=540-\frac {360}{n1}-\frac {360}{n2}-\frac {360}{n3}$ or $1=\frac 2{n1}+\frac 2{n2}+\frac 2{n3}$ and search for integer solutions.  You don't need any geometry once you get the angles.

I find the following triples $(3,7.42),(3,8,24),(3,9,18),(3,10,15),(3,12,12),(4,5,20),(4,6,12),(4,8,8),(5,5,10),(6,6,6)$
This makes a total of $17$, as you got.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but searching for integer solution will take a long time without the use of a computer (which is not required). But ill try your attempted and will get back to you (hopefully) soon!

Comment: It depends on what you call a long time.  I did use a spreadsheet and copy down, but you can bound the solutions pretty easily so it isn't too much work.

Comment: Ture, but you have to show there is $17$ solution and no more. So in your case, you must show that apart from the $17$ you come up with you must prove there exist no other. That, I think, will be tedious with your method. But I don't know what do you think?

Comment: No, I exhausted all the possibilities.  It takes care, but I got there quickly.  You need small enough sides on some polygons so you don't exceed 360, then enough that you get there.  For the three polygons case, I just made a column for each number of n1, which can only be $3-6$.  In each column I put a possibilities for n2 on rows using fill down, computed n3 and looked for whole numbers.  It didn't take long at all.

Comment: Interesting... thank you for the solution, I'll try to duplicate your method. But if I have trouble doing so, can I refer back to you for questions?

Comment: Sure.  I am around a lot

Comment: @Ross Millikan It is known there are 17 frieze/wallpaper types (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/52b4/a9188410ff9c3a966c91e3e8b1e8d589a458.pdf). Is there a connection with the present issue ?

Comment: @JeanMarie:  I am not sure. This question ignores the order of polygons around a corner, so three triangles next to two squares counts the same as two triangles, square, triangle, square.  It also does not demand that the pattern be able to be continued beyond one vertex.

Comment: @RossMillikan your method worked thoroughly, not time-consuming at all, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are small enough to count.

The smallest angle is $60$ and the largest angle is $< 180$ so there are between $3$ to $6$ figures.

If there are $3$ figures they average to angles $120$ so one is at most $120$ and one is at least $120$.

The angle of an $n-gon$ is $180\frac {n-2}{n}$.

So if there are $3$ figures one has at most $6$ legs and one has at least $6$ legs.

If the average six legs that's solution.

Solution 1: Three hexagons.

If one of them has fewer than $6$ legs we can try if it is a triangle, square, pentagon$

So

Case 1: One is a triangle.  Then the remaining $2$ will average $150$.

Solving $180 {n-2}n = 150$ give us $30n =360$ $n= 12$.

That's a solution 2.  A triangle and two dodecagons.  A dodecagon's angle is $180\frac {10}{12}= 150$.

Case 1a: One is a triangle. one has an angle of $180{n-2}{n} < 150$ and the third has an angle of $300- 180{n-2}{n} = 180{m-2}m > 150$.

So $\frac 53 = \frac{n-2}{n} + \frac{m-3}m;n< 12$ and so $5mn=3m(n-2) + 3n(m-2)$

$mn -6m=  6n$

$m = \frac {6n}{n-6}$ so $6< n < 12$ and you can have

$n = 7; 8; 9, 10$ and $m= 42, 24, 18, 15$ and those are several more solutions.

.... this will actually get tedious....

Case 2: One is a square and the remaining $2$ will average $135$.

Solving $180{n-2}n = 135$ give us $n=8$ and so

Solution 7: A square and two octogons.

If one has fewer $n< 8$ legs we goe $270 -180\frac{n-1}n = 180{m-2}m > 135$

So $\frac 32 = \frac{n-2}n + \frac {m-2}m$ so $3mn = 2m(n-2)+2n(m-2)$ so $mn = 4m + 4n$ and $m = \frac{4n}{n-4}$.

So $n=5,6$ and $m=20, 12$ are two more solutions.

Case 3:  If one is a pentagon.  We have one solution about so any other will require the second be a pentagon or higher.

We need $\frac {n}{n-2} + \frac {m}{m-2} = 252$ or average $126$ or average $6.5$ legs.  So we can have two pentagons and a third with an angle of $144$ which would mean  $\frac m{m-2} =\frac {144}{180} = \frac 8{10}$,

So solution 10: two pentagons and an decagon.

Or a pentagon, a hexagon and a third with an angle of $132$ which is $\frac m{m-2} = \frac {132}{180} = \frac {11}{15}$ which has not integer solution.

We can keep doing this....

Actually it gets easier as the averages are smaller.

For $4$ figures the average is $90$ or $4$ legs so that is a solution:  $4$ squares.

If one has fewer than $4$ legs it must be a triangle and the remaining have $300$ and the average of the three is $100 < 108$ so one must be a triangle or a square.

If you have two triangles then the remainder is $240$ which averages $120$.  So the third can have $3$ $4$ or $5$ or $6$ legs.  $3$ is out as that'd make the fourth angle $180$.  So are $4$ and $5$ by similar calculations.

So solution: two triangles, two hexagons.

If you only have one triangle, then you have a triangle and a square and the remaining two angles add to $210$ and average $105< 108$ so you'd have to have a triangle, two squares and .... a hexagon.

That's it for $4$.

If you have $5$ figures they average to $72< 90$ which must require at least one triangle.  The leaves $300$ for an average of $75< 90$.  So there must be at least two triangles.  That leaves $240$ for an average of $80 < 90$ so there must be at least $3$ triangles.  That leaves $180$ for an average of $90$

So solution: three triangles and two squares.

If we have a fourth less than a square we have four triangles and a remainder of $120$.  So solution: four triangle and a hexagon.

Finally for $6$ figure you have an average of $60$ which can only be $6$ triangles.

Averages.... logically cut things down.

=======

Another way of doing this is

$\sum \frac {k_i}{k_i-2} = 2$

Where there are $3$ to $6$ summands.  It's  ... the same.